# Conditional SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I need to move some data from one DB to another but as the layout is not the same, I need a to add a condition to this:

`If Genderbit == 1` (from `CRM.dbo.Person`), a string `'M'` should be inserted into `ewa.Ansprechpartner.Gender`, else a string `'F'` should be used.

```
USE easyWinArtTest
GO

INSERT INTO ewa.Ansprechpartner(Vorname, Nachname, Email, Telefon, Telefax, Gender)
   SELECT Forename, Surname, EMailAddress, Phone, Fax, [genderbit]
   FROM CRM.dbo.Person
```

How is this done with SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO ewa.Ansprechpartner(Vorname, Nachname, Email, Telefon, Telefax, Gender)
   SELECT 
       Forename, Surname, EMailAddress, Phone, Fax,
       CASE [genderbit]
          WHEN 1 THEN 'M'
          ELSE 'F'
       END
   FROM 
       CRM.dbo.Person
```

Use a `CASE` statement, based on the `Genderbit` column - if it's `1` then use `M` to be inserted, else `F`

Comment: @861051069712110711711710997114: **decades** of practice :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement in the select query to do the conditional substitution like so:

```
USE easyWinArtTest
GO

INSERT INTO ewa.Ansprechpartner(Vorname, Nachname, Email, Telefon, Telefax, Gender)
SELECT Forename, Surname, EMailAddress, Phone, Fax,Case when genderbit = 1 then 'M' else 'F' end
FROM CRM.dbo.Person
```